# Can't find my core data entity in scope when I changed its name

Tags: swift, core-data, scope, entity

[image]

I Can't find my core data entity in score. I changed the name of my core data entity from image to chickfila. Right the code is not appearing in scope. I don't know what would cause this. You can see what more is going in the 2nd photo I posted below. The reason I changed the entity name was because it was downloaded from a site.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataBaseHelper {
    
    static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    func saveImage(data: Data) {
        let imageInstance = ChickFila(context: context)
        imageInstance.img = data
            
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Image is saved")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you export the new model from the editor to the classes in the project?

Comment: Is code generation turned on for the entity? If no, did you also change the entity name in code? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/generating_code

Comment: It always a good idea to clean the build folder after changing your core data model.

Comment: @popeinvestor dont know how to do that.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you just hit cmd+k to do that?

Comment: This happened to me a couple of days ago. What I did was quit xcode, reopen the solution and build it. This fixed it, so I didn't go any further than this. Hope it helps.

Comment: After the deletion select your xcdatamodeled file and select in the Xcode menu Editor -> NSMangedObjectSubclasses... This generate your new files and add them to the project. You have to delete the old ones by hand...